# Sortable Drag and Drop with Collision?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What tools are available to facilitate drag and drop of items in the dom with collision detection, so I can drop an item into a folder by dragging the item over the folder?

I see jQuery has Drag and Drop, and I've seen plenty of tools for extending this to be sortable, but I haven't wrapped my head around how to trigger a function when an item is dropped on top of another item.

Comment: So you've looked at [jQuery droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/)? The example of triggering the function on drop is on that page if you click the view source link.

Comment: Wow, I totally missed that.  Should I delete this or do you want to make your comment an answer?  Maybe it wouldn't hurt to give that page more links.

Comment: Sure, I went ahead and made it an answer. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [jQuery droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/)? The example of triggering the function on drop is on that page if you click the view source link.